# Detect preferences in Settings app

Tags: ios, if-statement, settings

Is it possible to detect preferences in the Settings App, if so, how?

I have an app which I want to require that the 'Control Centre In Apps' option is toggled off. I know you can detect location services are available like so:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
```

Is it possible to do something similar for the 'Control Centre In Apps' option??

Thanks,
SebOH.